# "not subscriptable" problem -python ode solve

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods, ode

I'm trying to solve initial value problem(ode) using scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.
But 'type error : 'float' object is not subscriptable' has occurred

when i use odeint, it works.
i just change solver with same setting.

```
def f(z, t):

    c1 = z[0]
    c2 = z[1]
    
    dc1dt = -k1*c1 + k2*c2*(1-c1-c2)
    dc2dt = k1*c1 - k2*c2*(1-c1-c2) - 2*k3*c2*c2
    dcdt = [dc1dt, dc2dt]
    
    return dcdt

def main():

    k1 = 0.04
    k2 = 10.0
    k3 = 1500.0
    
    z0 = [0.9, 0.1]
    
    sol = solve_ivp(f,[0, 3000] , z0, method = 'RK45')
    return sol

main()
```

> ```
> TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The order for arguments in `f` is only valid for `odeint`, and even that can be avoided using the option `tfirst=True`. For `solve_ivp` it should be

```
def f(t,z):
```

The error occur because when array and scalar are switched, the solver tries to access components as of an array, but of a scalar variable.